# How do you find the index of a row that has a certain partial string?

Tags: r

I'm trying to find the index of every row in a dataframe (also containing integers) which has a certain string

I've tried to use which() and grep() but I kept getting integer(0) in return

Comment: Please share a few rows and columns of sample data, details about the "certain string" you are looking for, and the code you've tried on your best attempt.

Comment: Can you post some sample data?

Comment: The nicest way to share sample data is with `dput()`, e.g., `dput(your_data[1:10, 1:5])` for the first 10 rows and 5 columns of `your_data`. It will be copy/pasteable into R and include all the important data structure information. Alternately, you could share other code to create a sample data frame similar to your real data.

Answer (score 0):

In the absence of reproducible data, here's a `tidyverse` attempt with toy data:

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  v1 = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"),
  v2 = c("x", "y", "a", "z", "f"),
  v3 = c("x", "y", "a", "z", "s"),
  v4 = c("w", "c", "q", "p", "r")
)
```

Suppose you want to get the indices of every row that contains the string "a":

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  mutate(ind = row_number()) %>%
  filter(if_any(everything(), ~ str_detect(., 'a'))) %>%
  pull(ind)
[1] 1 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `base R`

```
which( rowSums(df == "a") > 0)
[1] 1 3
```

---

If it is partial string

```
which(Reduce(`|`, lapply(df, grepl, pattern = "a")))
[1] 1 3
```